# How to customize entity print pdf

Tags: 8

I've installed [Entity Print](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_print) in order to create PDF files. I've read the [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/entity-print/usage) to enable a twig template to customize the pdf output, but I don't know how to do simple things, in the twig file, like add a page header and footer, add a front page, etc. Are there any docs about how to customize it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on which print engine you're using. I am using the following entity-print.html.twig with the dompdf engine.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    {{ entity_print_css }}
</head>
<body>
{# The footer is repeated on all pages and must be printed first. #}
<footer>
    {{  footer  }}
</footer>
{%  if cover_page  %}
<div class="cover-page">
    {{ cover_page }}
</div>
{%  endif  %}
{# The header is repeated after the cover page for all pages. #}
<header>
    {{  header  }}
</header>
<div class="page">
    {{ content }}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The header and footer must be styled with position: fixed, after which they are displayed on every page.

I haven't found any great combined reference for the entity print module, but searching for what you want to accomplish along with your print engine's name should be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I installed WkHtmlToPdf, but only because It was the first option in the documentation. After read your answer I have installed dompdf and I will use this engine. I don't care the engine if I can do what I need. Thanks.